# Updating JPanel/JFrame not working

Tags: java, swing, paint, carousel

I have a class that creates a JFrame and needs to have one image displayed in the JFrame. Images must rotate every few seconds.

I've tried using repaint(), revalidate(), and validate() on both the JFrame and JPanel and none seem to work. Following is my current code to update the JFrame/JPanel. This code will wait 4 seconds and then display the fourth image, but I would like it to update every second with a new image.

```
public void startSlideshow(){
int i = 0;
Long oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
do {
   Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   if( currentTime - oldTime >= 1000 ) {
      img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Albums/" + album + "/" + imageNames.get(i)));
      panel.removeAll();
      panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      panel.add(img);
      panel.revalidate();
      panel.repaint();
      i++;          
      oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  // reset reference time
}
} while(i<imageNames.size());

panel.removeAll();
panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
panel.add(img);
panel.getRootPane().revalidate();
panel.repaint();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I've been banging my head for a while now. Thanks.

Comment: Even if that worked it would be a calamity as you're using a busy-wait loop. D:

Comment: @Boann This does not work, and I've tried about 10 different versions before this calamity. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you managing the 1 second wait?

Comment: Using a loop for waiting (even on a dedicated thread) is highly inefficient as it just burns down the precious CPU cycles. You would be better using a `Timer` here or `sleeping` in a separate thread and and dispatching the paint requests on the EDT through `SwingUtilities`.

Answer (score 2):

You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from process new repaint requests.

Instead of using a loop and `Thread.sleep`, try using a `javax.swing.Timer`

Take a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

You may also find it simpler to change the `JLabel`'s icon instead of creating a new `JLabel` on each time through...